# Converting int to hex bytes returns ascii characters not hex values

Tags: python

I am writing some socket code in Python3 and I am trying to send a byte array `'\x00\x00\x00\x01'` where the 1 is a user input integer from 0 to 10 (so 0 to a in hex).

I have tried making byte arrays using all the methods listed [here](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/how-to-convert-int-to-bytes-in-python-2-and-python-3/) and I always run into the same problem. When converting 9 or 10 into hex, I get '\t' and '\n' respectively.

If I run the loop

```
while(i<256):
    print(i, " = ", bytes([i]) )
    i=i+1
```

I get outputs with mostly hex values but some are ascii characters:

```
0  =  b'\x00'
1  =  b'\x01'
2  =  b'\x02'
3  =  b'\x03'
4  =  b'\x04'
5  =  b'\x05'
6  =  b'\x06'
7  =  b'\x07'
8  =  b'\x08'
9  =  b'\t'
10  =  b'\n'
...
```

I need these conversions to yield ONLY hex values since my receiving socket code cannot recognize anything else. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the receiving code expecting a string representation of a hex value? Have you tried sending `bytes([10])` to the receiver and examined the result?

Comment: Why do you think you want `hex`? That is only a convenience for us humans. When sending over the network then `b'\n'` *is* the value `10`. Its just that `bytes` thinks that you need to see an `ascii` representation.

Comment: I was interpreting a string value in my code then trying to send it as bytes. I fixed this interpretation problem and the receiving program no longer chokes on the \n character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send a byte, it seems you should use `struct.pack`:

```
pack_to_send = struct.pack("B", 10)
print(pack_to_send, len(pack_to_send))
```

Output:

```
b'\n' 1
```

Which is a 1 byte value.

Don't use this:

```
hex_ten = hex(10)
print(hex_ten)
value_to_send = hex_ten.encode('utf-8')
print(value_to_send, len(value_to_send))
```

Output:

```
0xa
b'0xa' 3
```

Here you start with a string which represents `10` as hex like this: `0xa`, but the `encode()` converts to bytes, but there are 3 bytes: the `0`, the `x` and the `a`

Comment: `struct.pack` generalizes to more cases (making `bytes` from integers larger than a byte), but `bytes([10])` (or `bytes((10,))`) works just fine for packing values made from `int`s in the range `[0, 256)`. Just don't forget that `list`/`tuple` wrapping; `bytes(10)` makes a length 10 `bytes` of all zeroes.

Comment: I read the link that was in the question, and, by a small margin, `struct.pack` was preferred. I have no preference myself.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I had an extra step in my socket code that converted the byte array into a string and was sending that. if I just omit that step the '\n' values appear to work as hex values (0xa, \x0a).